# Clipping/cutting more than one polygon layer in one step using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, clip, arctoolbox, arcgis-10.4

currently I am working with ArcGIS 10.4. My project contains several layers such as streets and buildings, as well as retail and residential areas for a large-area state in Germany. As this is a lot of data and I am currently focusing on a smaller region within this state, I am looking for an easy way to “cut” all data outside my region of interest, but retaining the symbols and the labels. To sum it up: Is there a way to do something like zooming into my project and cutting everything else outside in one step?

Comment: If original layers sitting on one workspace, e.g. Folder there is fast workaround. Is this a case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Clip tool under Analysis menu. (You can access Analysis Menu by clicking red toolbox on toolbar). Clip will help you clip the dataset by using a clip feature (in your case it's a polygon of your area of interest).

Since you want to clip multiple layers you can use Batch Clip by right clicking on the Clip tool.

Explanation regarding clip tool:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem clear whether you want to actually or just graphically clip those multiple layers.

Consequently, I think [Clipping the Data Frame](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm) may meet your requirement:

> If you need the data inside a data frame to be a shape other than
>   rectangular, you can clip your data frame's drawing to meet your map
>   specifications using the Clip options on the Data Frame tab of the
>   Data Frame Properties dialog box. Clipping does not alter the actual
>   data inside the data frame, even though data view also shows you the
>   clipped data. Labels honor the clip shape. They will redraw so you
>   will not see any clipped labels.